# How to install a forked gem of LinkedIn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to use the LinkedIn gem But not the one that I get when I type

```
sudo gem install linkedin
```

I want a specific one that somehow has done patches to. It is a fork of the original which is:

http://github.com/jbasdf/linkedin

I tried:

```
sudo gem install jbasdf-linkedin
```

But not succeed. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer which solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download sources from http://github.com/jbasdf/linkedin, and use "rake" command to build a gem locally

```
git clone http://github.com/jbasdf/linkedin.git
cd linkedin
rake build # (*)
find . -iname \*gem
# ./pkg/linkedin-0.1.8.gem
```

(*) system may ask you to install some required gems, such as 'jeweler' at this step

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. However, after installing the gem locally, when I do [require 'linkedin'], it will give me this error:MissingSourceFile in PublicController#job_detail, no such file to load -- linkedin

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you actually installed that gem with a `rake install` command or with `gem install ./pkg/linkedin-0.1.8.gem` ?

did you restarted your app after adding a `require 'linkedin'` ? did you put a `config.gem 'linkedin'` in your config/environment.rb ?